Calculate the limit $\displaystyle L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\prod_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{4k^3-3k+1}{4k^3-3k-1}\right)\right]$
Calculate the limit $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\prod_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{4k^3-3k+1}{4k^3-3k-1}\right)\right]$$
I’ve tried to find answers online but only came across the one that used Gamma function.Is there any particular solution to this type of problem that doesn’t require Gamma function?

You can write
$$\frac{4k^3-3k+1}{4k^3-3k-1}= \frac{(k+1)(2k-1)^2}{(k-1)(2k+1)^2}$$
Now, you have a telescoping product.

Ohh thanks I tried factoring it in photomath but turns out I typed the wrong equation. I typed +3k instead of -3k.
